# C won't execute

Tags: c, windows, cygwin, mingw, visual-c++-2010

I seem unable to run any C programs. I have tried Visual C, MinGW and Cygwin. When I try to start the program the terminal freezes, this happens for all 3 environments (except for visual studios which does not even get the terminal up). Consequently I have no error message to share. I have: restarted my computer and reinstalled MinGW several times with no effect. This seems like it would have to be something on the operating system level given that it is somehow affecting all 3 environments. This problem started following an ill fated attempt to install PCRE in MinGW.

I am running Windows 8.

At this point I am on the verge of installing a new OS. Does anybody else have an idea? because I am out of them.

**Note:** Please do not suggest new OS's, this is about fixing windows 8.

P.S. - I have tried a hello world program. The problem is not my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  printf("hello");
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I couldn't figure out how to fix this so I reinstalled my OS. Roll your eyes as much as you want, but it's the only thing that worked so consider the issue resolved.

Comment: Not enough detail here. Give us an exact sequence of events. Show a simple C program text, and show exactly what you typed at the command line to compile and run it, and what the response was.

Comment: Please post the code you are trying to compile and run. My guess is you are trying a simple "Hello World". But if you don't state that then how do we know your code isn't a `while(1)`?

Comment: From cygwin, do you run gcc -o hello hello.c?  And then try to run ./hello?

Comment: Half of Windows is written in C. If you couldn't run C programs, you wouldn't have got this far already.

Comment: Change the print to `printf("hello\n");` (`\n` at the end)

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker - that crashed from the ui in Visual Studios (VC 2010) and Netbeans (MinGW and Cygwin).

Comment: Code is fine. I won't suggest you switch OS, but I will suggest you fire up a command line console and give us the commands you type. Let's fix one thing at a time...first the compiler, then we'll worry about GUIs.

Comment: @kaylum and @bruceg `gcc -o hello hello.c` works just fine but `./hello` breaks the same way

Comment: @nnn how would that help?

Comment: @immibis if I was answering this question I would roll my eyes and say the exact same thing, however having spent about 2 days getting the same result from 3 separate environments, this is my only guess

Comment: If gcc produces a "hello.exe" in the current directory, and "./hello" hangs, then it's one of: (a) wrong version of compiler (you've unwittingly installed a cross-compiler or something?), (b) Incomplete installation of compiler or its libraries, or (c) your system is fundamentally broken--probably a bad DLL somewhere.

Comment: @nnn: Yes, there should be a newline, but that's not the cause of the problem.

Comment: `\n` is the newline character that makes the output to be actually printed (flushed). But in your case it should be flushed by program termination and you are right, not really needed.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker a and or b. The install process failed mid install of the PCRE library at the stage where it was checking whether to cross compile.

Comment: Never rule out option C in Windows. :-)

Comment: every day i come closer to switching but it is not practical at the moment.

Comment: do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Sure...uninstall everything you can, then try a clean install of MingW (it's smaller and simpler than Cygwin). Or go the all-MS route with Visual Studio. Make sure you have the right version--I think it's called "Visual Studio for Desktop Apps" or something like that.

Comment: Roll back the OS to the restore point you created before attempting to install PCRE.  That, or just restore from your last backups.  Nearly always, the restore point fixes the duff  install, no problem.

Comment: If you have an antivirus running, try to pause it or disable temporary. It may interfere with your generated program execution.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I have reinstalled mingw at least 4 times by now

Comment: Thanks everyone for your advice, but I think I am just going to take this opportunity to switch to windows 10

Answer (score 2):

Wow , I had the same problem on a Windows 8.1 PC. For us it turned out that reinstalling the Avast antivirus software fixed the problem. It seems like the Avast got hung up when it tried to scan the newly created exes. It did not give an error  or any indication. The exe created by Mingw just hung.

Answer (score 0):

that is sure a compatibility/platform problem. Have a copy of the software you're using for the specific bit(32 or 64), and install it.

If still the same problem, download opensource compilers like Borland, etc..If it works, then the IDE has the problem, if not, it's a hardware problem.

Answer (score -1):

Grab another computer B and try same install, if it works you have a hardware problem on computer A. Or a path problem or whatever is different between A and B.
If it shows same problem , you know you have an installation problem.

Comment: This provides a suggestion not an answer. How could it be a hardware problem?

Comment: Could have a non standard configuration, could have dual boot, could have multiple hard drives, could have little sister modified path, could have... At least trying this answer would remove a lot of possible problems, but if you don't like it, don't try.